# Problem with funcAnimation from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, nonetype

So I'm trying to write a program that will get serial data and then plot this data. The data is 128 numbers from 0 to 0xfff. I keep getting a cryptic error message about "Nonetype" object as no attribute update. I believe the rest of my code works because I've debugged most of the data that is stored and it appears to be formatted the way I would expect. I get no error about miss sized matrices or anything. Just the Nonetype error. I believe the error lies somewhere in Get_Serial_Data or the actual line ani = animation.funcAnimation. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
from threading import Thread
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib import style
import serial
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class serialPlot():
    def __init__(self, ax, serialPort='/dev/ttyUSB0', serialBaud=115200,
             plotLength=127, dataNumBytes=2):
    self.port = serialPort
    self.ax = ax
    self.xdata = np.arange(0, 127)
    self.data = np.arange(0, 127)
    self.line = Line2D(self.xdata, self.data)
    self.ax.add_line(self.line)
    self.ax.set_xlim(0, 128)
    self.ax.set_ylim(0, 0xfff)
    self.baud = serialBaud
    self.plotMaxLength = plotLength
    self.dataNumBytes = dataNumBytes
    self.rawData = bytearray(dataNumBytes)
    # sets up a byte array to accept input 2 bytes in size
    self.isRun = True
    self.isReceiving = False
    self.thread = None
    # self.csvData = []

    print('Trying to connect to: ' + str(serialPort) + ' at '
          + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')
    try:
        self.serialConnection = serial.Serial(serialPort, serialBaud,
                                              timeout=4)
        print('Connected to ' + str(serialPort) + ' at '
              + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')
    except:
        print("Failed to connect with " + str(serialPort)
              + ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')

def readSerialStart(self):
    if self.thread is None:
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.backgroundThread)
        self.thread.start()
        # Block till we start receiving values
        if self.isReceiving is not True:
            time.sleep(0.000000001)

def Get_Serial_Data(self, frame):
    # The first time we get data it most likely is in the middle
    self.rawdata = self.serialConnection.readline()
    # So we get the data back-to-back because second time will be all data
    self.rawdata = self.serialConnection.readline()
    # The data is CSV so we split at the commas and put into an array
    arr = str(self.rawdata).split(',')
    # The first number has a b' do to python's formating so we split the '
    first_number = str(arr[0]).split('\'')
    # turn the array into an numpy array while discarding b' and \r\n
    self.data = np.array(arr[1:128])
    # Reinsert the first number into the numpy array
    self.data = np.insert(self.data, 0, first_number[1], None)
    self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    self.line.set_data(self.xdata, self.data)
    return self.line,
    # self.csvData.append(self.data[-1])

def backgroundThread(self):     # retrieve data
    time.sleep(.000000001)      # give some buffer time for retrieving data
    self.serialConnection.reset_input_buffer()
    while (self.isRun):
        self.serialConnection.readinto(self.rawData)
        self.isReceiving = True
        # print(self.rawData)

def close(self):
    self.isRun = False
    # self.thread.join()
    self.serialConnection.close()
    print('Disconnected...')
    # df = pd.DataFrame(self.csvData)
    # df.to_csv('/home/rikisenia/Desktop/data.csv')


# def init():
#     line.set_data(xdata, [np.nan] * len(xdata))
#     return line,


def main():
    port = input("Which port # is KL25Z connected to? ")
    portName = 'COM' + port     # for windows users
    # portName = '/dev/ttyUSB0'   #for Linux
    baudRate = (115200)
    maxPlotLength = (128)
    dataNumBytes = (2)        # number of bytes of 1 data point
    # Initialize a serial connection all required variables.
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    s = serialPlot(ax, portName, baudRate, maxPlotLength, dataNumBytes)
    # plt.yticks(np.arange(0,0xfff,step=500))
    # plt.xticks(np.arange(0,127,step=8))
    # ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    # ax.plot(np.arange(0,127),label="Light")
    style.use("fivethirtyeight")
    plt.xlabel('Registry')
    plt.ylabel('Light')
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, s.Get_Serial_Data, blit=False)
    if len(s.data) is len(s.xdata):
        print("the length of both data is the same.\n")
    else:
        print("The two arrays have different sizes.\n")
    plt.show()

    # ans = input("Exit? ")
    # if (ans == "y"):
    #     s.close()
    #     exit()
    # s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()




  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1238, in _on_timer
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1460, in _step
    still_going = Animation._step(self, *args)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1191, in _step
    self._draw_next_frame(framedata, self._blit)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1210, in _draw_next_frame
    self._draw_frame(framedata)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1762, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "c:\Users\Joshua Edwards\AppData\Roaming\SPB_Data\.spyder-py3\FastSerialPlot.py", line 70, in Get_Serial_Data
    self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 402, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1649, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2628, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 728, in draw
    self.recache()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 644, in recache
    yconv = self.convert_yunits(self._yorig)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 195, in convert_yunits
    return ax.yaxis.convert_units(y)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1530, in convert_units
    ret = self.converter.convert(x, self.units, self)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 53, in convert
    unit.update(values)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Comment: Please post your whole stack trace as the information in it will help us help you

Comment: Added traceback to end of code.

Comment: If I had to take a stab in the dark I would say it's looking for something to update to the plot. I dunno how to fix it though because I put in an update function.

Comment: How are you running your code? (as a script, a Jupyter notebook or something else?)

Comment: Also, you should use `==` instead of `is` in `len(s.data) is len(s.xdata)`

Comment: The problem is that you are plotting strings instead of numbers. What is the purpose of this? Do you need the value in hexadecimal system?

Comment: I am running the program as a script in VS Code which I hope to eventually turn into an executable. I thought when I put the data into a numpy array that it would turn it into a decimal, but now that I look at it is in hex. I'll see if I can get it to convert it to decimal.

Comment: Oh I remember now I had used str to split the data up into a list, but I didn't know how to convert the lists into integers after the data was split up. I am unaware how to do this in python.

Comment: Finally fixed it. Thanks so much for all of your help. I had indeed not converted the hex values to integers. I had a bit more work I had to do to fix the dimensions on the x and y-axis to make them the same size (oddly my array of y data went from 0:127 to 0:128), but that was easy and now my graph works very well.